# Is there a way to reset Microsoft Edge Developer Settings while I exit from Edge? Or else any other way like using CMD?

Tags: html, microsoft-edge, web-developer-toolbar

I'm frequently changing my Edge Broswer Developer's settings.  So, for reset the Edge Developers mode, I do manually.

In order to reset, everytime I've to do all this `F12(Already I'm in Developer mode) > F1 (Settings) > Preferences > "Restore defaults and refresh"`

Now my question is, "Is there a way to reset Microsoft Edge Developer Settings while I exit from Edge?  If not, can I do it in any other way using CMD or something else...?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to auto restore Developer tools while exiting Edge.
But you can try using inPrivate mode in Edge, which will reset the devtools settings when closing the Edge.

Also, you could submit a feature request to the Dev Team by sending feedback(Press Alt+Shift+I) in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the information.